# Multithreading in opennetcf.orm (how to use SqlCeDataStore)

Tags: c#, multithreading, orm, compact-framework, opennetcf

I just started using the OpenNETCF.ORM framework, and I ran into a problem. What is the correct way to use SqlCeDataStore in a multithreaded application?

In a single-threaded application I would simply use a static field:

```
public class MyApp
{
    private static SqlCeDataStore _store;
    public static SqlCeDataStore Store
    {
        get {
            if (_store == null) {
                _store = new SqlCeDataStore("database.sdf");
                // other initialization stuff, DiscoverTypes() etc...
            }
            return _store;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I would use it like so:

```
var customers = MyApp.Store.Select<Customer>().ToArray();
```

After some research on SQL Server Compact, I found out that connections aren't thread safe, so each thread should have it's own connection. OpenNETCF.ORM does have an option to use a new connection each time you connect to the database. Should I just use that?

Another option would be to create a new SqlCeDataStore for each thread. Is that better?

What is the correct way?

Comment: What "problem" have you run into?  We use the ORM quite heavily in multithreaded applications in CE and Windows Desktop with SQL Compact as a back end without problems.

Comment: Sorry, not a problem as such, but I assume if I implement a multithreaded application wrong, it's going to come back and bite me sooner or later. I just want some pointers on how to use the ORM in a multithreaded application.

Comment: After dealing with some oddball threading issues and contacting MS I established that, in practical terms, SQL Compact CE is not thread-safe. If you need multi-threaded data access from your application I recommend you create a static singleton class to marshal all requests.

Answer (score 1):

We use SQL Compact in a variety of heavily multithread applications using the [OpenNETCF ORM](http://orm.codeplex.com) without any problems.  We run these on full Windows and Windows CE.

We use the "Maintain Maintenance Connection" connection behavior, where a new connection is created for all CRUD calls, but a single-background one is kept for doing maintenance work (creating tables, etc).  This gives good performance and a reasonable amount of thread safety.

Comment: ctacke, so is my code example OK? Just use a static field for SqlCeDataStore, initialize it at start-up, and let background threads use it?

Comment: Should be fine.  Personally I never use statics (or Singletons for that matter) but if that's how you enforce having just one, you should be fine.

Comment: Unless I missed something, your usage that creates a connection on every operation is thread safe because that connection is not shared across threads.  But the usage of @tvirk is multiple threads accessing  a single connection?

Comment: @tcarvin: his actual usage isn't fully clear to me. I think he's got a multi-threaded app (or is going to create one) and just wants to try to prevent running into trouble due to threads so he is asking for initial guidance.

Comment: @tcarvin, that is my understanding also. If I create a SqlCeDataStore for each thread, there should be no problem, but I would be creating connections and calling SqlCeDataStore.DiscoverTypes() every time I start a thread. ctacke, I'm trying to balance thread-safety, resources, and ease of writing code. Singletons and static fields make things easier to code, but it makes threading a nightmare.

Comment: I use one and only one DataStore instance in any application.